# bgcolor for alternative rows in a table dynamically using CSS

Tags: javascript, css-tables

How to give two different bgcolor for alternative rows in a table dynamically using CSS.

I don't want to use jQuery for solving this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use :nth-child() pseudo class

```
tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:green
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:yellow
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XUNg3/)**

[***Here***](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/css-selectors.html) is few more selector example.

Comment: @Sowmya: How can i remove the bgcolor of a particular row while i use this solution

Comment: you can assign the style for the row number like tr:nth-child(4) {style here}​   http://jsfiddle.net/XUNg3/11/ or you can give the class name for tat row and assign the style for that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 `nth-child` selector:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
```

> Represents the odd rows of an HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XUNg3/8/)***

Use `:nth-of-type(n)` **pseudo class**

as like this

```
tr:nth-of-type(2n){
    background-color:green
}
tr:nth-of-type(2n-1){
    background-color:yellow
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XUNg3/8/)***

**More info** ***[click here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype)***